# Выборка из БД по времени

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных, запрос, выборка

Подскажите как правильно реализовать выборку из БД по определенному времени?

Стоит задача раз в день на 7 утра выбирать запись за день.

То есть есть в базе значения :

> 05.03.2015 05:00:00
>
> 05.03.2015 06:00:00
>
> 05.03.2015 07:00:00 - на это время я все показания должен увидеть
>
> 05.03.2015 08:00:00
>
> 05.03.2015 09:00:00
>
> 06.03.2015 06:00:00
>
> 06.03.2015 07:00:00 - потом вот эти
>
> 06.03.2015 08:00:00
>
> 06.03.2015 09:00:00

Как построить правильно выборку? То нужно выводить одно значение в textbox причем не последнее а именно на 7 утра :(
Вот как я пытался это реализовать

```
Select * From sut.diet where datatime = DateTime('now' 7 HOUR)
```

но он не отрабатывает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такой вариант подойдет?

```
SELECT * FROM sut.diet WHERE DATE(datetime)=CURDATE() AND HOUR(datetime)=7;
```

Это будет работать есть поле `datetime` у Вас в именно форматe `datetime`, а не `unixtime`.

Answer (score 1):

Выборка, которая может работать по индексу (т.к. не используются функции от колонки). Собственно сегодняшний день + 7 часов:

```
select * from sut.diet where datatime = curdate()+interval 7 hour
```